# Combine 2 arrays based on key javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to combine two arrays based on the key "parent_id". Here are the arrays and the desired output:

Array 1: The item groups:

```
var itemGroups = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "value":"Item Group 1",
    "order":1
  },
  {
    "id":4,
    "value":"Item Group 2",
    "order":2
  }, 
  {
    "id":12,
    "value":"Item Group 3",
    "order":4
  }
];
```

Array 2: The items that are in groups:

```
var itemChildren = [
  {
    "id":68,
    "value":"An example item from Group 1",
    "parent_id":1
  },
  {
    "id":69,
    "value":"An example item from Group 2",
    "parent_id":4
  }
  {
    "id":76,
    "value":"An example item from Group 3",
    "parent_id":12
  }
];
```

The desired output:

```
var itemGroupsWithChildren = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "value":"Item Group 1",
    "order":1,
    "children":[
      {
        "id":68,
         "value":"An example item from Group 1",
      }     
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":4,
    "value":"Item Group 2",
    "order":2,
    "children":[
      {
        "id":69,
        "value":"An example item from Group 2"
      }     
    ]
  }, 
  {
    "id":12,
    "value":"Item Group 3",
    "order":4,
    "children":[
      {
        "id":76,
        "value":"An example item from Group 3"
      }     
    ]
  }
];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDITED:

```
var dataServiceGroups = [
  {"id":65,"value":"Group 1","order":1,"picklist_id":12},
  {"id":118,"value":"Group 2","order":2,"picklist_id":12},
  {"id":120,"value":"Group 2","order":4,"picklist_id":12},
  {"id":222,"value":"Group 3","order":3,"picklist_id":12},
  {"id":223,"value":"Group 4","order":5,"picklist_id":12},
  {"id":224,"value":"Group 5","order":6,"picklist_id":12},
  {"id":225,"value":"Group 6","order":7,"picklist_id":12},
  {"id":226,"value":"Group 7","order":8,"picklist_id":12},
  {"id":227,"value":"Other Group","order":9,"picklist_id":12}
];

var dataServices = [
  {"id":68,"value":"Item From Group 1","order":3,"picklist_id":13,"parent_id":65},
  {"id":228,"value":"Other Service","order":4,"picklist_id":13,"parent_id":227}
];
```

Comment: Is it OK to assume, as Richard does below, that the two input arrays are ordered identically?

Comment: Hi Simon, I'm not sure what you mean, although Richard's response does not appear to work on my actual data. I have updated the question with data closer to what I am using in my application as I am clearly missing something.

Comment: After further investigation the order is important. Essentially the children must be matched using the key "parent_id".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you transform array 2 into an object so that you can find things in it easily, and then use that to map array 1 into the result you want.

Have a look at the following

```js
var itemC = {}

itemChildren.forEach(function(child) {
  var tmp = {};
  tmp['id'] = child.id;
  tmp['value'] = child.value;
  itemC[child.parent_id] = tmp
});
  

var desiredOutput = itemGroups.map(function(item) {
  item[children] = itemC[item.id];
  return item;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this

```
itemGroups.map(function(object, index) {
    object["children"] = itemChildren[index];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a grouped array for the children and then add to the group objects:

```
var groupedChildren = [];

itemChildren.forEach(function(item) {
   var parentID = item.parent_id;      

   //Create the array for the group by parent id
   if(typeof groupedChildren[parentID] == "undefined") {
      groupedChildren[parentID] = [];
   }
   groupedChildren[parentID].push(item);
});

//Now add the grouped children to itemGroups
var itemGroupsWithChildren = itemGroups.map(function(group) {
  group['children'] = groupedChildren[group.id] || []; //put empty array if no children
  return group;
});
```